# Percentage of a layout inside RecyclerView visible on Screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there a way from which I can know what percentage of my layout inside a recyclerView is visible on the Screen.

The layout inflated inside RecyclerView has params of

`android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Edit added layout file

Layout file - custom_card.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/image_view_screen" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity Layout File.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using a Vertical LinearLayoutManager

Comment: you can get the width of your layout, and compare it to the width of recyclerView for example

Comment: using height here. The height of layout gives me its original dimensions, rather than the portion visible on screen.

Comment: show something to us then. Screenshot? Layout file?

Comment: @VladMatvienko edited

Comment: try this solution that will give you percent visible of each row.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49168492/5498233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much Try I figured it out. If it helps anyone.

Since my layout height was `match_parent`  it was easier for me. But this method will work for everyone with some calculations.

```
int firstItemPos=mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
View firstItemView=mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstItemPos);
int lastItemPos=mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
View lastItemView=mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastItemPos);
```

Now all items between `firstItemPos` and `lastItemPos` is visible 100%.

For firstItemView-

```
Math.abs(firstItemView.getY()) / firstItemView.getHeight()
```

Similarly for lastItemView-

```
Math.abs(lastItemView.getY()) / lastItemView.getHeight()
```

Answer (score -1):

use this;
in your adapter;

```
    private final Rect mCurrentViewRect = new Rect();
... your inits...
```

in your onBindViewHolder;

```
 View firstItemView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(position);
                                int pos= getVisibilityPercents(position);
```

use these metods;

```
  public int getVisibilityPercents(View currentView) {


    int percents = 100;

    currentView.getLocalVisibleRect(mCurrentViewRect);

    int height = currentView.getHeight();

    if (viewIsPartiallyHiddenTop()) { 
        percents = (height - mCurrentViewRect.top) * 100 / height;
    } else if (viewIsPartiallyHiddenBottom(height)) {  
        percents = mCurrentViewRect.bottom * 100 / height;
    }

    return percents;
}

private boolean viewIsPartiallyHiddenBottom(int height) {
    return mCurrentViewRect.bottom > 0 && mCurrentViewRect.bottom < height;
}

private boolean viewIsPartiallyHiddenTop() {
    return mCurrentViewRect.top > 0;
}
```

btw, dont remember get your recyclerView and linearLayoutManager to your adapter in constructor.

For more => https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager